# pip freeze doesn't show package version

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, freeze

Over the weekends I have upgraded my Ubuntu to 20.04, and I tried creating virtualenvironment with python 3.8.2, and pip install `requirements.txt`.
In requirement.txt, I am installing some code from private gitlab repositories.

Previously, if I do `pip freeze`, I was able to see all packages name and version (formatted as `package_name == version`.

However, if I do `pip freeze`, now I see something like this...

```
pkg1 @ file:///tmp/tmp44ir_jik
pkg2 @ file:///tmp/tmp5pijtzbq
...
```

(pkg1 and pkg2 are both from pip installing private git repo)

I would like to somehow display the version, but don't know how to.

I mean, `pip list` does show the version, but I am writing a script and would like to use `pip freeze` for it. 
How can I get `pip freeze` to show how it use to before (with the format as `pkg_name==pkg_version`)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, why is `pip3 freeze > requirements_patrick_mds_clean.txt` produce unusable requirements.txt files? what's the point of that command if it then makes pkgs depend on local paths/versions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `pip list --format=freeze` instead.

Comment: @ X Æ A-13  I see. Yes it now shows it in the format that I wanted. However, how do I change the format for **pip freeze directly**,  rather than doing 'pip list' then changing format?

Comment: I guess you'd have to downgrade with `pip install "pip<20.1"`. Or try and get the [PEP 610](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0610/) reverted.

Comment: @X Æ A-13 Downgrading it worked! It's also nice to know that pip list has --format flag to get what I want too. Thank you!

Comment: somehow i'm not surprised that elon's son is already answering questions on stackoverflow 

Comment: I don't get it, why is `pip3 freeze > requirements_patrick_mds_clean.txt` produce unusable requirements.txt files? what's the point of that command if it then makes pkgs depend on local paths/versions?

Answer (score 8):

I could not comment to answer the question by `Iowan` above; thus is redundant to the answer by `X Æ A-13`:

```
 pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: I don't get it, why is `pip3 freeze > requirements_patrick_mds_clean.txt` produce unusable requirements.txt files? what's the point of that command if it then makes pkgs depend on local paths/versions?